# Distributed priority queue (redis+tornado)

Tags: redis, tornado

I have 3 different priority queues A,B,C, stored on 3 different servers.

I have a central tornado server S, with 3 clients, connected to all three servers that needs to do a max reduction, where upon a GET:

1) query the head of each queue
2) the queue whose head has the greatest score is popped.

However, I need to be really careful of possible race-conditions when two GETS are processed simultaneously. I need to make sure that the operation occurs in lockstep like 1212 and not 1122.

I thought about using a blocking singleton to manage the all the instances, but I was hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: why dont you directly replace your tornado server with a single threaded process webserver ? that way you dont need to lock callbacks and you have no race conditions :P

Comment: while my comment was provocative, its a very simple and valid solution if you where a hard limit between 50 to 100 req/sec is acceptable